# Is there a code to know if a firebase-database data has loaded?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am been developing a kotlin app with firebase as database and I am trying to have a loading screen to pass to another activity, and I am trying to keep everything organized so I am trying to have a code that when the value above is loaded pass to another activity

```
        var myRef = database?.
                    getReference(tags?.USERS_DATABASE_VALUE.toString()).
                    child(mAuth?.currentUser!!.uid)

        myRef?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                snapshot?.children?.forEach {
                    val map = it.value as HashMap<String, Any>?
                    if (map!!.containsKey(tags?.COURSE_TAG_NAME)) {
                        if  (map[tags?.COURSE_TAG_NAME].toString().equals(sharedPreferences?.getString(tags?.CURRENT_COURSE_ACTIVITY, null).toString())) {
                            var courseStats = map[tags?.COURSE_ADVANCEMENT]
                            // if (loaded)
                            // {
                            //    GoToAnotherActivity
                            // }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, p0.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
```

Comment: When you `onDataChange` gets called, all current data at `myRef` has been loaded.  What is the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: I want to make sure it is completely loaded to start another activity

Comment: I have no idea what "completely loaded" means, beyond what I said: once `onDataChange` gets called for the first time, all existing data from the database is in the `DataSnapshot` that you get.

Comment: Anyways, Thank you :)

Comment: Frank van puffelen Man it actually works this way, thank you for answering you are awesome, sorry for the confusion, thank you for the work you do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call something from firebase database it has its own 'loading time' as Frank van Puffelen said in a comment below my question

Comment: Checkout this awasome libray for easy integration of firebase realtime database. link: github.com/Im-Mark42/FirebaseDatabaseAssistant